# What time frame is shown in Breaking Bad?

Tags: breaking-bad

In [Breaking Bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad) Mexico looks very rural and the US also look rural sometimes. So I am curious to know what time frame Breaking Bad is taking place at.

Comment: Most probably the time it was produced. There can be rural parts of the U.S., even more so in a smaller New Mexico town, I guess. Yet I haven't seen any episode of Breaking Bad, which makes this a completely uninformed side comment.

Comment: Population density of New Mexico averages 6.6 people per square kilometer.  When you take into account the large cities, this is why it looks rural.  The average population density of India is by comparison 368 per sq km.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can then assume 2009 is when [**Walter White**](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Walter_White) turns 50 years old due to his birth year being listed as 1959

From this, the final episode **Felina** takes place in 2011, exactly on the day of Walter's 52nd birthday.

Comment: The dates on Walter White's headstone are 7th September 1959 to 7th September 2011. Don't know if that's official or not - http://www.uproxx.com/tv/2013/10/walter-white-laid-rest-albuquerque-yesterday/

Comment: @Tom77 I stand corrected.  I could've sworn it was one of those that uses the year it airs as the year the story begins.

Answer (score -2):

Actually it was set in 2002 and we can clearly see the the date as 2003-11-30 in the episode 3x03 from the case number.

There is also this : http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Better_Call_Saul_Timeline

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this is somewhat lacking in detail unless you rewatch s3e3.  What 'case number'? ... also the date of 2002 somewhat flies in the face of all the other evidence .. such as Walter White driving an elderly 2004 Pontiac Aztek

Comment: The Better Call Saul Timeline is different from Breaking Bad, as it is a prequel